# SPFX : Undefined Hammer while trying to load third party javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

I have create a custom SPFX webpart and what I'm trying to do is to convert the HTML and JQuery flipbook into SPFx webpart. I've download this plugin and add all the reference. However, when it is loading, it is showing error

[image]

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Hammer is not defined
at p.zoomTouchSupport (wow_book.min.js:211)
at p.zoomSetup (wow_book.min.js:201)
at new p (wow_book.min.js:114)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (wow_book.min.js:122)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at n.fn.init.e.fn.wowBook (wow_book.min.js:122)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (LoadA.js:31)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.add [as done] (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I have put the reference in the webpart.ts as `require('wowbook');` and config.json

```
"wowbook": {
  "path": "./src/webparts/flipBookWebPart/assets/js/wow_book.min.js",
  "globalName": "jQuery",
  "globalDependencies": [
    "jquery"
  ]
},
```

I even have declare in config.json for hammerjs, but no luck

```
"hammerjs": {
  "path": "./src/webparts/flipBookWebPart/assets/js/hammer.min.js",
  "globalName": "hammerjs"
},
```

In previous HTML file, there is no include for any hammerjs. Just wondering what when wrong here.

Comment: I think we might need more information to assist in diagnosing.  I don't see anything wrong with the snippets you've posted, which means the problem must be somewhere else, config, package, component, etc.  I know its a pain to post all of your code or put it somewhere where we can all see it, but I just don't think we can see enough of your code yet to find the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo to include custom js library in SPFx solution.

```
var alertify:any=require('../ExternalRef/JS/alertify.min.js');
```

[image]

Call function.

```
alertify.yourfunction
```

Comment: I have used this step and it is calling. but i still got the error while trying to load the webpart. the error is coming from the js file. The js file is running fine if I using normal html page.